# Newton interpolation with derivative data

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, interpolation

Using Newton-form interpolation, find an expression for the polynomial interpolant  $p\in\mathcal{P}_4$, such that  $p(0)=f(0)$,  $p(1)=f(1)$, $p'(0)=f'(0)$,  $p'(1)=f'(1)$, and $p''(0)=f''(0)$. Check that your expression is correct by trying it on  $f(x)=(1+x)^4$.

Comment: The way you implement derivatives is to repeat the $x$ value(s) where you want to enforce $n$ derivatives $n+1$ times. Then when the tableau for Newton divided differences would ask you to compute $\frac{f^{(k)}(x)-f^{(k)}(x)}{x-x}$, you replace it with the desired value of $f^{(k+1)}(x)$ instead.

Comment: @Ian can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: There's not much more to say, if you know how to do Newton divided differences without derivatives then you should be able to set this up using my hint. You can also Google "Hermite interpolation" to find plenty of writing on the subject.